# Problem running python/matplotlib in background after ending ssh session

Tags: python, ssh, background, matplotlib, tkinter

I have to VPN and then ssh from home to my work server and want to run a python script in the background, then log out of the ssh session. My script makes several histogram plots using matplotlib, and as long as I keep the connection open everything is fine, but if I log out I keep getting an error message in the log file I created for the script.

```
 File "/Home/eud/jmcohen/.local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2058, in loglog
    ax = gca()
  File "/Home/eud/jmcohen/.local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 582, in gca
    ax =  gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/Home/eud/jmcohen/.local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 276, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/Home/eud/jmcohen/.local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 254, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/Home/eud/jmcohen/.local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 90, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/Home/eud/jmcohen/.local/lib/python2.5/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1647, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:10.0"
```

I'm assuming that it doesn't know where to create the figures I want since I close my X11 ssh session. If I'm logged in while the script is running I don't see any figures popping up (although that's because I don't have the show() command in my script), and I thought that python uses tkinter to display figures. The way that I'm creating the figures is,

```
loglog()
hist(list,x)
ylabel('y')
xlabel('x')
savefig('%s_hist.ps' %source.name)
close()
```

The script requires some initial input, so the way I'm running it in the background is

```
python scriptToRun.py << start>& logfile.log&
```

Is there a way around this, or do I just have to stay ssh'd into my machine?

Thanks.

Comment: can you run vnc session? alternatively, there is XFree NX program, but I never used it. it is like screen for X11 session.

Comment: I don't really know much about vnc. I thought it was more for controlling a computer on a local network? I think the problem is with x11 closing, so when I close the vnc session wouldn't it give the same results?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you're running in interactive mode by default, so matplotlib wants to plot everything to the screen first, which of course it can't do.

Try putting

```
ioff()
```

at the top of your script, along with making the backend change.

reference: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ioff

Comment: Awesome, that did the job. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 25):

I believe your matplotlib backend requires X11.  Look in your matplotlibrc file to determine what your default is (from the error, I'm betting TkAgg).  To run without X11, use the Agg backend.  Either set it globally in the matplotlibrc file or on a script by script by adding this to the python program:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Comment: I added that line to the beginning of my program but still get the same error message.

Comment: only that worked for me :) make sure those 2 lines precedes any other matplotlib's pyplot / pylab / backends references. quote: 
"This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot, or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time"

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is a stupid answer, but if you're just running a console session, would 'screen' not suffice? Detachable sessions, etc.

Comment: This might be a stupid reply to your possibly stupid question :)
What do you mean by console session, 'screen', and detachable session?

The way I'm running this is I'm home on my OS X machine VPN then SSH via terminal into my linux box at work.

Comment: @Jamie, the unix screen command allows you to detach from your terminal and then re-attach later.  Once you are at the terminal prompt, type screen, launch your program.  Now just close out of your SSH client.  Next time your reconnect on that box, type "screen -R" and you are back to where you left off.  Of course, see the screen manpage for lots more details.

Comment: Actually screen gives me the same display error (when running matplotlib code in an interactive console with ioff()) - apparently it doesn't play nice with matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a *nix OS the problem is your session is terminated and all  processes requiring a session are also terminated when you disconnect. More specifically all your processes are sent a SIGHUP (signal hang-up). The default handling of SITHUP is to terminate the process. If you want you script to continue it needs to ignore the signal. The easiest way to do that assuming you start your script via the command line it to run it using the nohup command:

```
nohup python scriptToRun.py << start>& logfile.log&
```

nohup normally sends standard out and standard error to the file nohup.out in the current directory. Since you're redirecting already output nohup.out will not be created.

Comment: his problem is due to X11 connection failing.

Comment: Adding nohup to the beginning didn't seem to do anything, got the same error message.