# TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable on EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ipython, anaconda

I'd like to use iPython on an Amazon EC2 (Linux AMI). I've installed Anaconda and started iPython to test out some scripts I've already created. Right now I am only interested in running it in Terminal (**not** as Notebook).

At the beginning of my code I always do:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
```

However, I tried CTRL + C from my text editor and then using %paste in Terminal I get the error:

```
TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

If I try to ssh -X name@host as per this suggestion [No display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable using tkinter through ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309085/no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable-using-tkinter-through-ssh), I get:

```
/opt/X11/bin/xauth:  file /Users/adrianp/.Xauthority does not exist
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

To fix that issue I tried https://superuser.com/questions/249045/x11-forwarding-from-amazon-ec2-ami but still got a warning:

```
 Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
```

And the same error:

```
TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Per this suggestion [Generating a PNG with matplotlib when DISPLAY is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined) (which seems irrelevant but I've tried everything) I did:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

before importing anything else and still get the same error.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? I'd really like to use the paste magic function to input functions/etc.

Comment: Another variation when trying to use magic paste function is `TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:10.0"`

Comment: Concerning the localhost error...tried this but still can't get magic paste to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443702/problem-running-python-matplotlib-in-background-after-ending-ssh-session

Comment: This appears to be an IPython 3.0 bug, FWIW I am having he same problem on an ARM server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more of a linux/X11 issue than a python question. Also, this process will probably be overkill - you'd be better just running ipython locally or launching a web notebook.

Anyway, you should:

- install tigervnc
- run vncserver (since this is an internet-facing server, use a secure passphrase or block the port in the firewall)
- install tk (I think you have already done this)
- edit sshd_config (most likely /etc/ssh/sshd_config) and enable
  X11Forwarding (X11Forwarding yes).
- login to your server passing the -Y option to ssh (ssh -Y user@server)

You should then be able to start ipython and use %paste.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed response. I'm buried in other projects so I'll need a bit of time to test this out.